# Sqlalchemy + mysql, incremental key reuse

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

i have an api-key that i need to assign to users, they need to be unique per user, but may be reused starting as 0 [0,1,2,3,4,5...] but they have a limit, and it's feature-specific (not all users need them unless requested).

for now I've been adding 1 to the highest number as user request keys:

[ 0, 1, null, 3, 6, 7, null, 10, 11, 12, null, null...]

but this is incrementally getting to the limit, and i need to reuse them: [ 2, 4, 5, 8, 9...]
how can i get the lowest unused value in sqlalchemy to always reuse the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of the SQLAlchemy syntax on this one, but sql-wise I think you might want to do something like as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016907/mysql-find-smallest-unique-id-available). Quoted:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.ID + 1) AS nextID
FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
ON t1.ID + 1 = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

If you're having trouble finding the proper SQLAlchemy way, you can always use the `with_statement` or `execute` methods on the session object (lets you freely define the SQL statement). In general, consult [this page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/query.html) for information on how you might go about building this.