# SQL find next available string key

Tags: mysql, key

I need to find the next available ID on a table that has keys that are strings. [I have followed an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016907/mysql-find-smallest-unique-id-available). My example below:

Dishes Table (first columns)

```
Table_id
DSH0000000003
DSH0000000004
DSH0000000005
DSH0000000007
```

SQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DSH',LPAD(MIN(SUBSTRING(t1.dish_id FROM 4) + 1), 10, '0')) AS nextID
FROM dishes t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.dish_id 
          FROM dishes t2
          WHERE SUBSTRING(t2.dish_id FROM 4) = SUBSTRING(t1.dish_id FROM 4) + 1)
```

Output:

```
DSH0000000006
```

If I delete #5 then it returns #5 but it does not return "DSH0000000001".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use variables to build consecutive ids, then compare where's first non-matched id:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('DSH', LPAD(seq, 10, '0')) AS k
FROM
  (SELECT
    @seq:=@seq+1 AS seq,
    num
  FROM
    (SELECT
       CAST(SUBSTR(table_id, 4) AS UNSIGNED) AS num
     FROM
       t
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
        MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(table_id, 4) AS UNSIGNED))+2 AS num
     FROM 
       t
     ORDER BY
       num) AS ids
   CROSS JOIN 
      (SELECT @seq:=0) AS init 
  ) AS pairs
WHERE
  seq!=num
LIMIT 1
```

Fiddle is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a17e7/7).

Comment: Hi Alma Do, it seems your query will not return the next ID if there are no gaps in the id list (that is the highest ID number). See SQLFiddle here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a17e7/1). I am afraid your SQL is above my knowledge.

Comment: @TheRealPapa I've noticed. Little fix was needed. I've updated

Answer (score 0):

You should add a test of your start value. With your current approach you can only get values greater than the minimum value that exists in your table.

You could use IF() to distinguish the two possibilities.

Comment: Hi VMai, thanks for the reply but how would you check for the start value in the query? Thanks