# how to get lowest available unique value

Tags: mysql, min

im trying to get the lowest available unique value but with some parameters.

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016907/mysql-find-smallest-unique-id-available)

and my statement will look like this

```
SELECT MIN(t1.cloakroomnumber + 1) AS nextID FROM Wardrobe_CloakTable t1
LEFT JOIN Wardrobe_CloakTable t2
ON t1.cloakroomnumber + 1 = t2.cloakroomnumber
WHERE t1.payingcustomerID = 2 AND t1.cloakroomsection = 'B' AND t2.cloakroomnumber IS NULL
```

but this is returning something that is not correct at all.
So the question is where should i put my WHERE to the MIN argument.

my tables are like:

```
ID (unique not important)
payingcustomerID (FK - thats why i need to get lowest for just 1 customer)
deviceID (not important)
terminalnumber (not important)
qrcode (not important)
cloakroomsection (defines if query is inserted in the same physical section)
cloakroomnumber (defines the unique number but its only unique in the
                 way that its unique in the same section AND for the same
                 paycustomerID)
```

if i have 5 different cloakroomnumbers in my database with same cloakroomsection and same payingcustomerID looking like

```
1
2
3
5
6
```

i want to be able to get number 4

the statement in the start i got from the other post is working correctly without my try to manipulate it. but its not taking into account payingcustomer and cloakroomsection. thats what im trying to add.

Comment: is cloakroomnumber a column with unique values?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you add a simplified example, people can faster understand what you need.

Comment: Would be helpful to see your tables and expected output.

Comment: what you really want to acheive please elaborate it more

Comment: add your table architecture,data and expected output

Comment: i'm sorry i'm still trying to get used to SO's way of settings up stuff. But i tried to edit my first post, hope it helps just a bit.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: i need this because its a cloakroom where hangers will get available again when people are leaving the area. So in the start the numbers 1-2-3-4 and so gets used. Then later number 3 leaves. and is avaible to get reused.

Comment: But can't the cloakroom attendant just see that the hanger is available?!?!

Comment: Anyway, this is different scenario. We now know that you have a table of all hangers. So you just select the lowest available hanger.

Comment: in theory he could, i made them a system where they can type in the hanger number themself. but its on android and they want it to autogenerate numbers. Fine i did that but at some point it need to take lowest available when it reach the limit. I know they could go find the hanger and see it as free. But it can be quite hard in between 500 cloaks. i could also add an overview of the whole cloakroom and they could click the free ones. But this is the solution im getting requested.