# Smallest unused id from mysql table with django

Tags: mysql, django

suppose i have a table A(id, x, y). I've inserted where id = 1 to 35 but 15, 18 etc. is there a way to find the smallest unused id in django.

what should i do to insert with smallest available id available whenever i add an item.

there are some similar questions i found on stackoverflow that explains how to do it in mysql(links below). but as i am very new to django i am not getting how to do that in django.

[mysql find smallest + unique id available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016907/mysql-find-smallest-unique-id-available)

Comment: Why does the value of the id matter?

Comment: That is not the way to go. Is is an auto-increment ID? Then don't mess with it